# R Dplyr Mutate with Simple condition

Tags: r, dplyr

Start with the Minimum example:

```
test <- data.frame(
    RowNum = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, NA, NA)
  )
```

If the following 2 pieces code work:

```
## Chunk 1
test <- test %>%
dplyr::mutate(rotCertCount = (
    (is.na(RowNum))
  ))

## Chunk 2
test <- test %>%
dplyr::mutate(rotCertCount = (
    if (TRUE) 0 else 1
))
```

why does the following piece not work?

```
test <- test %>%
dplyr::mutate(rotCertCount = (
    if (is.na(RowNum)) 0 else 1
))
```

Error:

```
Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `rotCertCount = (if (is.na(RowNum)) 0 else 1)`.
Caused by error in `if (is.na(RowNum)) ...`:
! the condition has length > 1
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I mean, say what you like but that error message means nothing.

Comment: The error message speaks plenty, you are evaluating a condition more than once, I e. you are applying is.na() to a vector, which yields a vector of TRUE or FALSE. Replace your if-block with ifelse(), which is vectorized.

Comment: `test %>% dplyr::mutate(rotCertCount = ifelse(is.na(RowNum), 0, 1))`. In R, `if` works on a "length-one logical vector" condition. To make a test that relates separately to each row, use `ifelse` or the dplyr variant `if_else` which is pickier in that it requires the true and false results to be the same type; it won't coerce them to be so like ifelse.

Comment: @mhovd I thought that an evaluation like that inside a dplyr function is applied to each individual row element in turn. Why would it apply to the whole vector? Am I to understand that there is a different form of if else that must be used in this case? If so the treatment of context is (in my opinion) completely nonsensical in R.

Comment: It will work like you expect if you add `rowwise()` in the prior row -- each row's `if` will get evaluated separately, but it is more idiomatic and much faster to use `ifelse` / `if_else` -- these are vectorized, meaning they get compiled once and applied to all rows. https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/

Comment: I get what you mean about the error - I think what is unstated by the error is that `if` is looking for a single true or false. I can't find the documentation for base `if` oddly!

Comment: You don't even need `ifelse`, R's logical values already are `0/1` so just coerce to integer with `as.integer(is.na(RowNum))` or with the more obscure `+(is.na(RowNum))`.

Comment: ...or `1 - is.na(RowNum)` to get 0s for NA, 1s otherwise.

Comment: I don't see a question here, it is clear from the comments and from countless older posts why the `if(){}else{}` would fail in this case.  The issue seems to be with the error message, if so, then this post is more relevant at [dplyr github issues](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues).

Comment: @Mark You can't find it? Strange. `help("if")` seems kinda obvious.

Comment: Having a `"well written question"` is not enough to have it open. Confusion, as I mentioned already, clarified in many older posts, and in the comments above. Any valid answer to this "why" would be a copy of existing answers. "not a clear" error message better be addressed to developers at GitHub.

Comment: @Roland I was doing `?if`... didn't know about `help()`!  thanks for the tip